# Xamarin Forms: Can't align Frame/Entry and Button in a grid

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have a Frame around an Entry and a button in a grid. However, I can't get the frame/entry to fill up or center next to the button.

Here's my xaml:

```
<StackLayout>
        <Grid>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="*" />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Frame Grid.Column="0" BorderColor="{DynamicResource PrimaryColor}" CornerRadius="5" IsClippedToBounds="True"
                   Padding="0" Margin="10,10,5,5" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" HasShadow="False">
                <Entry x:Name="queryEntry" Text="{Binding QueryString}" FontSize="{DynamicResource StandardLabelFontSize}" 
                    Placeholder="Search string" ReturnType="Search" ClearButtonVisibility="WhileEditing" 
                    VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" AutomationId="TextSearchEntry" BackgroundColor="#F0F0F0"/>
            </Frame>
            <Button Grid.Column="1" Text="Find" Command="{Binding FindTextCommand}" Margin="0,10,10,0" WidthRequest="80"
                    Padding="0" IsEnabled="{Binding QueryString, Converter={StaticResource NonEmptyStringValue}}"
                    VerticalOptions="Center"/>
        </Grid>
        <Label Text="No Results Found." HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" IsVisible="{Binding WereNoResultsFound}"/>
        <ScrollView>
            <CollectionView ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" SelectionMode="None" >
                <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
```

Here's how it's laying out on iOS:

[image: iOS Layout]

If you notice that both of the controls are starting at the top of the row but the button is taller. I would like to have them both automatically be the same height. I've tried many different settings but can't seem to get it to work. I thank anyone in advance for assistance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this , Button `HeightRequest="35"` and Frame `Margin="10,15,5,5"`

```
<Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Frame Grid.Column="0" BorderColor="Blue" CornerRadius="5" IsClippedToBounds="True"
               Padding="0" Margin="10,15,5,5" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" HasShadow="False">
            <Entry x:Name="queryEntry" Text="FInd" FontSize="Medium" 
                Placeholder="Search string" ReturnType="Search" ClearButtonVisibility="WhileEditing" 
                VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" AutomationId="TextSearchEntry" BackgroundColor="#F0F0F0"/>
        </Frame>
        <Button Grid.Column="1" Text="Find"  Margin="0,10,10,0" WidthRequest="80"  HeightRequest="35"
                Padding="0" BackgroundColor="Blue"
                VerticalOptions="Center"/>
    </Grid>
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! Works great. I was hoping for some sort of auto-layout feature that would do it automatically for me.